# SQlite joining results

Tags: sqlite, full-text-search

I have a table , let's call it `Customer` and a FullText Table `Customer_t` which based on the text in the table that is indexed.

```
Customer
   ID
   Name
   City

Customer_t
   ID
   SearchText  (just the Name and City put together)
```

Using `Full Text index` and the `SQlite MATCH` term, how do I get a list of all the Customers that match a search in Customer_t. Basically a join, but the join table, which is the search source is a Full Text Index table.

Stuck.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a join:

```
SELECT *
FROM Customer
JOIN (SELECT ID
      FROM Customer_t
      WHERE SearchText MATCH '...')
USING (ID)
```

or a subquery:

```
SELECT *
FROM Customer
WHERE ID IN (SELECT ID
             FROM Customer_t
             WHERE SearchText MATCH '...')
```